# can't achieve this htaccess redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a `maindomain.com` that contains a website, and some pages here should be redirected temporarily to my subdomain `tmp.maindomain.com`.
So I used this redirection, it redirect to the `tmp.maindomain.com` and I get an infinite loop redirection to `tmp.maindomain.com`:

```
redirect 301 /mypage.php https://tmp.maindomain.com/mypage.php
```

My target is that, if any user tries to access `https://www.maindomain.com/mypage.php` or `https://maindomain.com/mypage.php` he should be redirected 302 to `https://tmp.maindomain.com/mypage.php`.

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: I mean: redirect 302 /mypage.php https://tmp.maindomain.com/mypage.php 301 was just used for testing

Answer (score 0):

You will get an infinite loop if the subdomain and main domain point to the same place (or a subdirectory of the later).

In which case you will need to use mod_rewrite (as opposed to mod_alias) and explicitly check the requested hostname.

> some pages here should be redirected **temporarily**

But you are also using a 301 **permanent** redirect. You need to use a 302 instead. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so you need to make sure all caches are cleared before testing.

Try the following at the *top* of the subdomain's `.htaccess` file, before any existing mod_rewrite directives.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^mypage\.php$ https://tmp.maindomain.com/$0 [R,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) does not start with a slash (unlike the mod_alias `Redirect` directive).

The `$0` backreference contains the URL-path that is matched by the entire `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `mypage.php` in this example. This simply saves repetition, since you are redirecting to the same URL-path at the target.

This defaults to a 302 temporary redirect.